# Production Build doesn't load images

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, production

[image: My React folder structure look like that.]

I'm trying to display a `profile picture` for a `profile`.

The user can `replace` his `profile picture` with another one.

I do that by `deleting` the old image and add the new one that's uploaded BUT with the same name, that means after refresh React is supposed to pick up the same image because it has the same name as before.

***THIS DOES WORK IN DEVELOPMENT BUILD***

But in **production build**, React doesn't do that because it uses the `static` folder as its primary source of images.

I do this process with Nodejs when i `store` the image to this path.
`./client-side/build/Provider/ImageURL`.

I tried storing it into the `static` folder
`./client-side/build/static/media`.

But that doesn't work at all as React adds like `salt` in the image name like that : -
[image]